# simple javascript code does not work: var count = colors.push(“red”, “green”);

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var colors = new Array();
            var count = colors.push(“red”, “green”);
            alert(count);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried this on firefox and IE, do you think that my version of JavaScript needs to be updated?

Comment: "Does not work" is not very clear. What does it do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: How would you update your version of JavaScript? Define "does not work."

Comment: Dou you want to print the length of the array or the array itself? If it's the second you need alert(colors)

Comment: it is your quotations that are breaking... use the normal "

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, which ones? It's easier to help you debug if you post what errors you're receiving.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use real quotes, either `"` or `'`, for example:

```
var count = colors.push('red', 'green');
```

The quote character you have used is illegal and is showing the JavaScript error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

**Demo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      var colors = new Array();
      var count = colors.push('red', 'green');
      // alert(count);
      alert(colors[0]);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! that was the right solution. Now, I noticed that if I try this code in Internet Explorer 8, it does not work: alert(colors[0]);  <-- it should give an answer of "red". Now this does work in firefox.. but why not IE8 ?

Comment: There must be something else that IE doesn't like. I have added a demo that is showing the expected output `red` in IE8 for me.

Comment: you said: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  <-- where can I find this kind of error message ?

Comment: JavaScript errors are reported by browsers either in the built-in _Console_ (in modern browsers) or as a message in the status bar at the bottom of the window (in IE8 for example). IE8 shows a warning triangle indicating a problem with the page at the bottom and if you click on it, the error `Invalid character` is displayed. Chrome and Firefox show the error in their console - see [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy pasted your code in jsFiddle  and it looks like your quotes are illegal characters (copy pasted from word / web?).  Try typing them out again and it should work.

Comment: Oh you mean what andyb said a couple of minutes ago?

Comment: Yeah, but I was busy typing my answer when he did ;)